# C++ : Skipping variable value from user

Tags: c++

This is my program need: user has to enter numerator or denominator or both and i need to display the lowest ratio possible. If it is 6/9 then should displayed as 2/3.

I used hcf calculation to convert the ratio. But I am stuck in the part : 'user can enter numerator or denominator or both`

Here is my code skeleton:

```
class number
{
  public:
    int num;
    int denom;
    number()
 {
    num=1;
    denom=1;
 }
    void getvalue(int x, int y)
    {
      num=x;
      denom=y;
    }
    void ratiocalculation()
    {
    }
};
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    number obj1;
    cout<<"Enter num and denom";
    cin>>x>>y;
    ...........
    ........
}
```

This code cover the the user can enter both numerator and denominator part.

Here how to get only numerator or only denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide on a way to communicate the two options with the user. For instance you can have something like this:

```
cout << "Select an option:\n" 
     << " 1: to enter both numerator and denominator\n"
     << " 2: to enter only numerator\n"
     << " 3: to enter only denominator\n"
     << " 4: to exit\n";

int option;
cin >> option;
```

And then it should be obvious how to continue. As entering only a numerator and a denominator is not distinguishable(from what is being entered stand point) there is no other way to deal with both options.

Comment: So there is no other way except asking user what you are ready to input?.I thought something like default argument will help. It actually defeat the purpose of default arguments

Comment: @sameer You could also use command line parameters to differentiate, or parse a line instead of using the standard `>>` operator.  However, both of these require the user to know more about how to communicate with your program and quite a bit more work on your part than Ivaylo Strandjev's solution.

Comment: @sameer default argument will not help. Think of your program as a black box that only takes the user input as argument. Now if all you enter is a single integer there is no way you can tell if this is a denominator or a numerator.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following example, where you assure that input is a number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
  return !s.empty() && std::find_if(s.begin(),
    s.end(), [](char c) { return !std::isdigit(c); }) == s.end();
}

int main()
{
  int x, y;
  std::string num;
  std::cout << "Enter numerator: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, num);
  while (!is_number(num)) {
    std::cout << "Input is not a number , enter again: ";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
    num.clear();
    std::getline(std::cin, num);
  }
  x = stoi(num);
  std::cout << "Enter denominator: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, num);
  while (!is_number(num)) {
    std::cout << "Input is not a number , enter again: ";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
    num.clear();
    std::getline(std::cin, num);
  }
  y = stoi(num);

  // GCD(x, y);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am not in to STL yet, are you checking the entered value is number or character ??

Comment: @sameer I'm checking if entered value consists solely from digits.